# How can I create a custom skin and a set of buttons without loosing windows aero controls in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to be able to use all the snapping functionality built into the regular default wpf window. I was wondering if there was a way to add custom buttons and color theme without creating a custom window from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Start by [Creating a Copy of the Default Template](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/using-blend-to-find-default-style-xaml/).

[image]

2 - Modify as needed.

3 - ???

4 - Profit.

Comment: Do you know of a good place to get started with editing in blend. I assume I want to change the boarderbrush but i'm new to all this and can't seem to make the boarder actual change colors. I also want to change the control Icons to my own